# When using Bootstrap 3 and 4, what is a proper way to set a maximum width for the page content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The reason of doing this is so that when the window is too wide, and the layout is that the information on the page will be too loose if it is spread out beyond a width of `1000px`.

I could think of

```
body { max-width: 1000px }
```

but what if you can have footer that can span the whole width? So what about if the main content part of the page is inside

```
<div id="root">

</div>
```

or

```
<main id="main">

</main>
```

then just use

```
#root { max-width: 1000px }
```

or

```
main { max-width: 1000px }
```

Is it a good way to do it together with the styling rules of Bootstrap 3 and 4?

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#containers

Answer (score 1):

There's not a defined proper way. The Bootstrap way is to use a `container` (defined width), or `container-fluid` (full width). If you want a page width other than `container`, define a custom "wrapper" class, and use a container-fluid inside it...

```
.wrapper {
   max-width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

On 2nd thought, it would be better to customize `container` since you want the content centered like the container.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container.container-custom {
        max-width: 1000px;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/k5QtAfRysh

It's really a custom approach either way, and there's no "proper way"

Comment: so you mean I also could do `.container, .container-fluid {  max-width: 1000px }` ?

Comment: by the way the `wrapper` should be similar to using the `main` or `#root` container

Comment: you mean leave `.container, .container-fluid` alone and don't modify their styles directly?

Comment: ok, i see that you use a `.container-custom` to set the `max-width`... so again, you didn't want to directly modify `.container` and `.container-fluid`

Comment: No, not a good idea to modify the classes directly since you may want to use them elsewhere such as in the header or footer.

Comment: hm... so if you use `.container-custom`, how about just remove the `@media` and then for every `.container` and `.container-fluid` also use `.container-custom` and then `.container.container-custom { max-width: 1000px }`. Another method I tried: just have the `<main></main>` contain all the content, and use `main { max-width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }` to make it centered horizontally

Comment: Either way works. As I said there's no defined proper way.

Comment: I usually try to avoid using `@media` unless absolutely need to